# NGROK warning bypass in iframe

Tags: iframe, request-headers

I have an ngrok server running and I wanted to bypass this warning so what do I put in my request to bypass this? I need to send a request header in an iframe somehow.

Is there any way I can do this in an iframe?
I'm a newbie involved with this kind of stuff.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxXky.png

Comment: Even if you click on visit site, are you able to visit the your website ? I get repeatedly the same warning and somehow not able to bypass

Comment: You can try https://pinggy.io , much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send `ngrok-skip-browser-warning` as a header with any value. Alternatively you can set a custom User-Agent request header. It is stated on the page itself :)

[image]